# tableadapter.update doesn't work?

Tags: c#, wpf, database, tableadapter

I have a problem that drives me crazy...
I have a local database (.sdf) on my PC en a database on the internet (MySQL), both with same structure.
I first load data from the internet in the dataset via the dataadapter and secondly I load some local data in the dataset.

Now I want to store the data from internet also in the local database, I tried it with the Update statement. This has to work, but everytime I run the program (debug) and I went back to the local database (via the database explorer, right click on table, Show Table data...), the internet data has not been saved!

To be clear I do see both data (local en from internet) in my dataGrid1.

What do you think is the problem?

```
        klantenTableAdapter.ClearBeforeFill = false;

        DigiLocalDataSet dataset = new DigiLocalDataSet();

        string MyConString = "SERVER=server;" +
                    "DATABASE=db;" +
                    "UID=uid;" +
                    "PASSWORD=pass;";
        string sql = "SELECT klantnr, geslacht, voorletters, roepnaam, achternaam, tussenvoegsel, straat, huisnr, subhuisnr, postcode, plaats, telthuis, telmobiel, email, geboortedatum FROM klanten ORDER BY roepnaam";

        MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection(MyConString);

        MySqlCommand cmdSel = new MySqlCommand(sql, connection);

        MySqlDataAdapter da = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmdSel);


        //Fill from internet
        da.Fill(dataset.klanten);


        //Fill from local database
        klantenTableAdapter.Fill(dataset.klanten);

        klantenTableAdapter.Update(dataset.klanten);

        //dataset.AcceptChanges();

        this.DataContext = dataset.klanten.DefaultView;
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your 'internet' rows have the _Unchanged_ status. Better to copy the records to a new Table, maybe keep 2 Datasets.

Comment: If what Henk says is true (very probable ;-)) then try to edit some "internet" data. Those rows should then become visible after the Update.

Comment: That doesn't work, in fact what I want to do is to copy the internet MySQL table data to an exactly the same table on my local machine. I thought this is a right way, but maybe it isn't. Does one of you guys have an idea to make this hapen??

Answer (score 0):

New to this, but don't you need to call **SaveChanges** too to commit it to the database?

Comment: No, that would be SaveChanges on an EF context.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that de db reference uses a relative path. The Dataset wizard proposes to *copy* the database to your output directory. However in the Server explorer you are still examining the original database. Could that be it? ;-)